# Remove Bootstrap from my simple_form gem after install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, simple-form

I used a command to make the simple_form gem work well with bootstrap. I'm pretty sure it was:

```
$ rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

But I've decided I'm not going to use Bootstrap as my Rails app will be mostly used with mobile phones. I'm going to go with jQuery mobile. I make use of both jQuery Mobile and Bootstrap in my app, at present, and they seem to be clashing sometimes in the use of class names. I'm just going to use jQuery Mobile which I think is sufficient. Any thoughts or useful articles on this would be handy.

So, what would be the command for undoing the above? I know it scattered a few files around the place in my app folder and I'd like to undo it to keep it clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following two commands:

```
rails d simple_form:install --bootstrap ## Destroy the existing configurations for simple_form

rails g simple_form:install  ## Generate the clean configurations for simple_form
```

When you initially ran the generator for `simple_form` with `--bootstrap` option, it created bootstrap compatible configurations for `simple_form`. The changes that have been specifically made for bootstrap are spread across multiple files. It would be hard to cherry-pick them and remove unless you know exactly what needs to be removed and what to keep for `simple_form`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Your d command got rid of my simple_form.rb but in my config/initializers folder I noticed a simple_form_bootstrap.rb still hanging around in there, so I ran rails d simple_form:install --bootstrap, which got rid of that. Then I ran your g command - so it's all like new. Marking you as correct because you put me well on the right track, but might be handy to update for future users.

Comment: It was a typo. Updated the answer. Was too focused on the detailing.